# Express Gateway disable TLSv1.0

Tags: node.js, express, tls1.0, express-gateway

I'm working with "[Express Gateway](https://www.express-gateway.io)" which is running on a node server.

As of my understanding, configurations should be done in gateway.config.yml file.

I couldn't find how to disable TLSv 1.0 from the documentation provided by "Express Gateway".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the late reply!

We support this scenario but unfortunately it's not exactly that straightforward. This should do the trick:

```
https:
  options:
    secureOptions: 67108864
```

This is basically hardcoding the constant value that disables TLS1. If you could open an issue on the repository I'm quite sure we can find a more systematic solution for this.

Thanks!